# Calculate multiple modelField from one Formfield

Tags: python, django, modelform

I need extract multiple ModelField value from one FormField. where I should do this? in `clean_<field>` functions? with `cleaned_data` mutation? form `__init__` function? in `model.save` or `form.save` function?

model:

```
def normalize_name(name):
    # some code
    return name

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name           = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    normalize_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
```

form:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model  = MyModel
        fields = ('name',) # or normalize_name? or both?
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by " extract multiple ModelField value from one FormField". But, if you want to have "normalize_name" in the form, you should add it into the fields tuple too....  ('name','normalize_name',)...

Comment: user only enter `name` in html form. but in model both `name` and `normalized_name` need validation. `normalized_name` must calculated from `name` and then validated.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, I would do the stuff in the `save()` function.

`__init__(self)` is called before entering the data into the form so it can't  do anything with attributes.

Theoretically, `clean_name` could work (in my opinion), but it should be used for validation.

The `save()` method is called after the `name` attribute is validated so you can get the `name` and do some stuff with it (normalize_name(name))

```
def save(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    name = self.cleaned_data['name']
    self.instance.normalized_name = normalize_name(name)
    return super(YourFormClass, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you mean that you generate `normalized_name` using `name` and the form is valid when `normalized_name` meets some conditions, do it inside clean_name(self).

```
def clean_name(self):
    name = self.cleaned_data['name']
    normalized_name = normalize(name)
    if not validate(normalized_name):
        raise ValidationError("Something is wrong)
    return name
```